# Java Multithreading | Finding all possibilities

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop

I am trying to make a simple program that finds all the possibilities of getting a score with the available scoring methods in American Football.

Here is my code that works and returns all the possiblities for the score

```
for (int a = 0; (a * sf) <= score; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= score; b++) {
            for (int c = 0; (c * td) + (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= score; c++) {
                for (int d = 0; (d * tdE) + (c * td) + (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= score; d++) {
                    for (int e = 0; (e * td2) + (d * tdE) + (c * td) + (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= score; e++) {
                        if ((((a) * sf) + ((b) * fg) + ((c) * td) + ((d) * tdE) + ((e) * td2)) == score) {
                            count++;
                            // System.out.println((a)+" Safties | "+(b)+" Field Goals | "+(c)+" TD | "+(d)+" TD w/ E | "+(e)+" TD w/ 2PC ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to make it so I can split up the score into multiple threads so the program can handle larger numbers much much quicker.

Currently I am testing with 4 Threads, and I am using this loop.

```
for (int a = min; (a * sf) <= max; a++) {
        for (int b = min; (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= max; b++) {
            for (int c = min; (c * td) + (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= max; c++) {
                for (int d = min; (d * tdE) + (c * td) + (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= max; d++) {
                    for (int e = min; (e * td2) + (d * tdE) + (c * td) + (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= max; e++) {
                        if ((((a) * sf) + ((b) * fg) + ((c) * td) + ((d) * tdE) + ((e) * td2)) == max) {
                            main.inc();
                            System.out.println((a)+" Safties | "+(b)+" Field Goals | "+(c)+" TD | "+(d)+" TD w/ E | "+(e)+" TD w/ 2PC ");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For example, if the score was 500.
Thread 1 would get 1-125,
Thread 2, 126-250,
Thread 3, 251-375,
Thread 4, 376 500.

I have it splitting up properly and giving the right min-max, but it still does not work properly. I believe it has to do something with where each for loop begins, but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If more explaining is needed, just let me know

Comment: Yeah... this seems quite simple.

Comment: @MuratK. then why do you post that and not suggest anything?

Comment: Your question really needs an [mcve] rather than only snippets.

Comment: There's no mention of threads in the code you've supplied. What problem are you having? FWIW I see no value in having more than one thread per CPU core. It looks as if you could just divide the outer loop by that number and give each core an equal chunk of work.

Comment: You cannot just replace the score value in the nested loops . Only the outer loop could split  (like proposed by DL).  He wrote a good answer except BS about threads and cores, apparently he just couldn't explain it better

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can only do the min/max on the outer for loop.  See if it works like this:

```
for (int a = min; (a * sf) <= max; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= score; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; (c * td) + (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= score; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; (d * tdE) + (c * td) + (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= score; d++) {
                for (int e = 0; (e * td2) + (d * tdE) + (c * td) + (b * fg) + (a * sf) <= score; e++) {
                    if ((((a) * sf) + ((b) * fg) + ((c) * td) + ((d) * tdE) + ((e) * td2)) == score) {
                        count++;
                        // System.out.println((a)+" Safties | "+(b)+" Field Goals | "+(c)+" TD | "+(d)+" TD w/ E | "+(e)+" TD w/ 2PC ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To run it with the min/max applied to all 5 for loops, partitioning the score at each level, you would need 1024 threads (4*4*4*4*4 = 1024.)  Thread 1 would do 1-125, 1-125, 1-125, 1-125, 1-125 on each of the 5 for loops respectively.  Thread 2 would do 1-125, 1-125, 1-125, 1-125, 126-250. Thread 3 would do 1-125, 1-125, 1-125, 1-125, 251-375...and so on.  Basically like a 5 digit, base 4 number incrementing from 00000 to 33333.  However, because the algorithm is CPU and/or I/O bound, you probably won't see any performance gain if you increase the number of threads beyond the number of CPU cores you have on your machine.  I would stick with partitioning just the outer loop by 4 as you probably intended.

**EDIT:** Here's a working implementation:

```
public class ScoresTest implements Runnable {

    public static final int SCORE = 500;
    public static final int SF = 2;
    public static final int FG = 3;
    public static final int TD = 6;
    public static final int TE = 7;
    public static final int TD2 = 8;

    int min;
    int max;

    public ScoresTest(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int a=min/SF; a*SF <= max; a++) {
            for (int b=0; a*SF + b*FG <= SCORE; b++) {
                for (int c=0; a*SF + b*FG + c*TD <= SCORE; c++) {
                    for (int d=0; a*SF + b*FG + c*TD + d*TE <= SCORE; d++) {
                        for (int e=0; a*SF + b*FG + c*TD + d*TE + e*TD2 <= SCORE; d++) {
                            if (a*SF + b*FG + c*TD + d*TE + e*TD2 == SCORE) {
                                System.out.println("SF: " + a + ", FG: " + b + ", TD: " + c + ", TE: " + d + ", TD2: " + e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ScoresTest(0, 124));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ScoresTest(126, 248));
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new ScoresTest(250, 374));
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(new ScoresTest(376, 500));

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Gabriel Vince - The algorithm is extremely CPU intensive or perhaps I/O bound so increasing the number of threads beyond the number of CPUs you have on your machine is unlikely to improve performance.  That's where I was going with having 1024 cores on your machine.